# Совет по таблицам MySql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть товар у которого `3 размера` и соотв. `3 цены`, сейчас всё сделано на `JS` и при клике на 1 из 3 `input[type="radio"]` подставляется цена и размер указанные в его атрибутах. Хочу сделать правильные таблицы в Mysql, подскажите структуру таблиц, я так понимаю нужны 2 таблицы:

```
1) Products:
id
name
size_id


2) Sizes:
id
size
price
```

И как-то связать `size_id` из `Products` и `id` из таблицы `Sizes`?

Работаю с БД первый раз и запутался(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наоборот. Товару все равно, какие у него размеры. А вот размер принадлежит конкретному товару

- Products (id, name)
- Sizes (id, size, product_id, price)

Где поля `id` - это автоинкрементные поля, а поле `product_id` - внешний ключ, который ссылается на поле `id` таблицы `Products`

Comment: а `product_id` получается нужно вручную ставить?

Comment: Почитай про ключи в таблицах MySQL, `sizes.product_id` должен быть внешним ключом к `products.id`.

Comment: @СергейКозин Дополнил ответ